# How to change the values dynamically in the NSMutableArray in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have 10 buttons and i wrote the button action using switch case. When i click each button, it will increase some amount of values. If i am using 10 different variables for set the count value variable, it will work. But is any other possible way to achieve this?

I want to change the values dynamically in the mutable array.

For Eg:

```
    -(IBAction) btnAction : (id) sender{

       switch (btn.tag) {

                case 0:
               // amountArray is mutable array.

                    startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 10;

                    //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 1:

                startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 15;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];


                break;

            case 2:
                 startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 20;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 3:
                 startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 25;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];


                break;

            case 4:
                 startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 30;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];


                break;

            case 5:
                  startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 35;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 6:
                  startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 40;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 7:

                         startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 50;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 8:

                        startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 60;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 9:
                 startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 20;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            case 10:
                        startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 20;

                //NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount];

                        //[amountArray addObject:str];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

In table view,

```
cell.textLabel.text = [amountArray objectAtindex:indexPath];
```

If i am using single variable, it won't set for all the conditions, so how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Devan What do you store in NSMutableArray ? I mean how many objects are there ? Which object you want to update ?

Comment: @Jennis, Actually i am having 10 buttons, so i want to store the 10 objects in the mutable array. I want to get the values which buttons user clicks. For eg: user clicks 3rd button, i will display 30. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. It will work.

```
int startCocoCount;

NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    [dataArray addObject:@"0"];
}
```

And for the method it will as follows:

```
-(IBAction) btnAction : (id) sender{

    switch ([sender tag]) {

        case 0:

            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 10;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 1:

            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 15;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 2:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 20;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 3:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 25;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:3] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 4:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 30;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:4] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 5:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 35;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:5] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 6:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 40;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:6 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:6] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 7:

            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 50;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:7 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:7] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 8:

            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 60;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:8 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:8] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 9:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 20;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:9] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        case 10:
            startCocoCount = startCocoCount + 20;

            [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:10] intValue] + startCocoCount]];

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually if i am using this code, the startCocoCount value should be retain which means, in first button i have clicked and get the value 90 and goes to the second button, now it would be increase 90 + 15. But i want to, when clicks the every button in the first time the value should be start with zero. That's why i am asking, how to use single variable to change the values properly. Thank you!

Comment: Here you can intialize startCocoCount to 0 each time button is pressed. I changed my answer.

Comment: If i set the startCocoCount = 0; means, every time it set as zero. when moves to one button to another.  For eg: If i have first button value 90 and second button value 80, then again comes to the first button, then the value is zero. So It doesn't work.

Comment: Now you check again. I changed my answer.

Comment: What you have edited?. It was same as you have posted the first answer.

Comment: I have chaged to [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dataArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue] + startCocoCount]]; but it was before: [dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startCocoCount]];

Comment: @AppAspect let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1465/discussion-between-pugal-devan-and-appaspect)

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumber` allows you to store into an array. To access the array by index you will need to pre-populate the array with `NSNumber`s so that the indexes are available.

```
//You will need to know the index otherwise use a dictionary with named keys
NSNumber *num = [amountArray objectAtIndex:index];
num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[num intValue] + 20];
[amountArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:num];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify like this

```
 -(IBAction) btnAction : (id) sender{

startCocoCount = startCocoCount + btn.tag;
}
```

You can set the tags of the button to hold the values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how it's possible, in first button i have to add 10 and second button 15, third button 25. so each buttons having different values, so how can i do that? Thanks

Comment: @PugalDevan I think he means each button has its own tag

Comment: Yes thats rite. Each button has its own tag.

Comment: You can do it using interface builder or where ever you create those buttons. Write the tag value into it.